# Return a String from Method After Delay

Tags: objective-c, grand-central-dispatch

I am trying to return a string from a method after a 10 second delay. The delay is because there is some processing that needs to take place before the string gets returned. This is what I've got so far:

The issue is that the string gets returned right away. Any recommendations? Thanks!

```
-(void)getSomethingInTenSecondsCompletion:(void(^)(NSString *result))aCompletion {

    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(10.f * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        aCompletion(@"Got Something");
    });
}


-(NSString *)getSomethingInTenSeconds {

    __block NSString *result;

    [self getSomethingInTenSecondsCompletion:^(NSString *result) {

        NSLog(@"RESULT: %@", result);
    }];

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Use a completion handler instead of using a return value.

Comment: Make `getSomethingInTenSeconds` accept a block like `getSomethingInTenSecondsCompletion` does and pass it through.

Comment: What other delay is there, but the processing?  Or are you speaking of something concurrent, that is dependent on another task, and has to wait until that task is done?  (If you're simply mocking something, just sleep for 10 seconds, or am I missing something?)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback everyone, my objective is simple (I believe). All I want to do is call a method with type NSString, and have it wait 10 seconds (asynchronously so that processing continues), then return the requested string.

Answer (score 3):

Your `-(void)getSomethingInTenSecondsCompletion:` already does that, but you cannot use a return like that.

You would use the `-(void)getSomethingInTenSecondsCompletion:` on the places you would use `-(NSString *)getSomethingInTenSeconds`, and put the logic to handle the string in the completion:

```
- (void)someMethod {
    //some code
    [self getSomethingInTenSecondsCompletion:^(NSString *result) {
        //do something with the result string, 
        //for example, updating the UI
        [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{
            self.textView.text = result;
        }];
    }];
}
```